# Jenkins fails to execute while running as winservice

Tags: jenkins

I am able to run my script successfully from jenkins when jenking is opened using war file.
If set the jenkinks as winservice my script is failing in middle.

I am trying to run a start.bat file from jenkinks, this bat file calls a java class. again this java class uses bat file to run a plink command.

Execution stops at this stepsif jenkinks is running as winservice and also I can't view the output as it is running in background.

Is there any way to make jenkinks behave normal while running as winservice

Thanks

Comment: you need to give us some logs and some code

Comment: Actually I am using ant to build my job as My batch file again calls different bat file(some of this may contains connection to other machines as well).                                                          This was not being handled by jenkins. So, I used this as per "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build"                                     SO, Jenkinks job is only to initiate the batch file. It won't monitor whole execution.The log file also contains only this initation and with success status

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1.** Go to services (hit windows key, type "services", select "Services" from the list of matches).

**2.** Find the Jenkins service and open it's properties

**3.** Switch to Log On tab

**4.** Change the service to run as you, instead of local system user.

**5.** Restart service.

Alternative is to fix local system user account (probably environment variables) so it works as local system user.

Comment: I tried this, earlier my script used to stop at some point, but after making this change the script is not even starting execution

Comment: That does not make much sense without more details, please improve the question, especially add Jenkins build's console output showing the error.

Comment: As mentioned in my above comment there is no error message displayed in console output. It is showing as success. But the batch file which is supposed to start execution is not started

Comment: So you have build step, which prints something to the build's console output when you run Jenkins one way, and nothing when you run Jenkins another way? If your bat has @echo off at first line, comment that out to see if you then get something. I find it unlikely that Jenkins would just skip build step without anything relevant in console output.

Comment: Jenkins just calls the batch file using swapping process(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build). This batch file calls a javaclass and I am redirecting output to some text file here so that I can have complete execution log. When I check this log, the log details contains all logs creating folders, printing it details etc., the log is stopped at plink command(command used to execute some shell script in server), no logs after this command where as when I run jenkins normally evrything works fine